# Blender Cycles gives black rendering when using GPU and saved as OpenEXR

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

So I tried rendering a scene that I made for a school project. I have a tight deadline so I rendered it with two windows of Blender open, 1 rendering with CPU and the other with GPU. The renders were shown completely fine in the render result but when I opened the OpenEXR files, I saw that the ones rendered with the GPU were completely blank and the ones with the CPU were fine. Can anyone help me to find a way around this? I am rendering at 32 samples if that helps.